# How to update particular row in table without affecting all in ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just learning and building one simple Dashboard using AngularJs .

It about to display the order receive time, process time, delivery time using
my own rest service. 
 In current working version a request is sent to my Rest and displaying all orders in dashboard on every 10 seconds.

When a no.of orders are increasing the rest msg size became huge. so  my rest is modified to return updated orders or new orders.

Is there any way to add/update row to existing table using angularjs ?

```
{
  "records": [

    {

      "OrderId": "101",
      "CustName": "John",
      "OrderReceived": "Nov 19, 2015 4:53:00 PM",
      "OrderProcessed": "Nov 19, 2015 4:54:06 PM",
      "OrderDelivered": ""

    }, {

      "OrderId": "102",
      "CustName": "Raju",
      "OrderReceived": "Nov 19, 2015 4:58:00 PM",
      "OrderProcessed": "",
      "OrderDelivered": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

And my **HTML dashboard table** is,

```
<html>
  <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="css/dashBoardStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> OrderId </th>
            <th> CustName </th>
            <th> OrderReceived </th>
            <th> OrderProcessed </th>
            <th> OrderDelivered </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
          <td>{{order.OrderId}}</td>
          <td>{{order.CustName }}</td>
          <td>{{order.OrderReceived}}</td>
          <td>{{order.OrderProcessed}}</td>
          <td>{{order.OrderDelivered}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And **Controller** is,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
      $interval(function() {
        $http.get("http://localhost:5060/RestService/eosOrderJson")
          .success(function(response) {
            $scope.update = response.records;
          });
      }, 10000)

      $http.get("http://localhost:5060/RestService/eosOrderJson")
        .success(function(response) {
          $scope.names = response.records;
        });
```

Comment: the base answer is just add it to the collection, ng-repeat will bind it automatically, don't replace the whole collection

Comment: Now i able to iterate and update / add orders manually. it would be great if i work with collections. because it may reduce iteration time. but no luck in adding to collection and replacing orders.